# How to prevent next npm command from running?

Tags: npm, npm-scripts

I'm trying to run preflight checks via npm before allowing other scripts to process.

The following works but I'm wondering if there's a better way

**package.json**

```
"deploy": "npm run _deploy:preflight && npm run _deploy:real",

"_deploy:preflight": "node ./build-utils/deploy-preflight.js",
```

**build-utils/deploy-preflight.js**

```
if (checksFail()) {
    console.log("--------------");
    console.log("preflight checks failed!");
    console.log("--------------");
    process.exit(1);
}
```

The problem isn't so much that it doesn't work, it's that the console is then littered with a huge npm ERR / stacktrace and I'd much rather just see the clean "preflight checks failed" message and still have it prevent `npm run _deploy:real` from running

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I agree - npm can be rather noisy/verbose at times.

The following suggestion assumes you keep `deploy-preflight.js` as it currently is, whereby you continue to exit with an exit code `1` on error, i.e. `process.exit(1)`.

- The npm [`--silent`](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config.html#shorthands-and-other-cli-niceties)  command-line option, or it's shorthand equivalent `-s`, is probably the most favoured!. However, it does require you to include it with the CLI command that you run.

  For instance:

  ```
  $ npm run deploy -s
                   ^
  ```

  or

  ```
  $ npm run -s deploy
            ^
  ```